# 500 error on localhost when submitting form using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm fairly new to PHP and I'm having trouble sending test emails out from my local host.

I have a 3 field form where I'm hoping that I can have a user submit the form & be able to see a success message without the page refreshing. I get the error message that I have set in the code but for some reason, I'm unable to actually get the emails to send/have a success message appear.

Here's my code:

js

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    var form = $('#ajax-contact');

    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })
        .done(function(response) {

            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');


            $(formMessages).text(response);


            $('#name, #email, #number').val('');
        })
        .fail(function(data) {

            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('error');


            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

mailer.php

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
            $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $number = trim($_POST["number"]);

    if ( empty($name) OR empty($number) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Sorry, there seems to be a problem submitting your details, please try again or contacts us";
        exit;
    }
    $recipient = "example@example.co.uk";
    $subject = "$name has given you their details to call them back";
    $email_content = "
    <html>
    <style>
    body {
        background-color: white;
    }

    .email-container{
        background-color:#c1c1c1;
        max-width:400px;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:30px 10px;
        border-radius:10px;
        border: 2px solid #515151;
    }

    </style>
    <body>
    <div class="email-container">

    Dear example, <br />
     <br />
    A potential client has requested a call back. Their details are as follows: <br />
     <br />
    Name: $name\n <br />
    Email: $email\n\n <br />
    Telephone: \n$numer\n
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>"
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Sorry, there seems to be a problem submitting your details, please try again or contacts us";
    }

} else {
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}

?>
```

HTML

```
<form class="requestcall-form" id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
  <input type="text" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Contact number" required>
  <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="form-messages"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer is correct, I thought I'd offer a better solution for dealing with large blocks of text, [heredoc strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). No worrying about unescaped quotes ruining your day. Using this, your code would look like this:

```html
...
$recipient = "example@example.co.uk";
$subject = "$name has given you their details to call them back";
$email_content = <<< HTML
<html>
<style>
body {
    background-color: white;
}

.email-container{
    background-color:#c1c1c1;
    max-width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:30px 10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border: 2px solid #515151;
}

</style>
<body>
<div class="email-container">

Dear example, <br />
 <br />
A potential client has requested a call back. Their details are as follows: <br />
 <br />
Name: $name <br />
Email: $email <br />
Telephone: $numer
</div>

</body>
</html>

HTML;
$email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";
...
```

Comment: I have tried both these suggestions but getting a 500 error, I've tried to trace back my through my PHP but i'm a little lost now.

Answer (score 1):

there is something wrong with how you output `$email_content`. String is not formatted correctly
check the `<div class="email-container">` and change it to `<div class='email-container'>`

also, add a (;) after your `$email_content`

Comment: I have tried both these suggestions but getting a 500 error, I've tried to trace back my through my PHP but i'm a little lost now.